# Vus.js Laravel Update records not working

Tags: laravel, vue.js

i am beginner of vue.js and laravel programming successfully done add records and view records from the database.but i can't update the records.when check the error through the console. it displayed the following

**Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)**

i don't know how to solve them.my api is working successfully.
what i done so far i attached below.

**Laravel**

**Routes**

```
Route::put('/update/{id}',[App\Http\Controllers\ContactController::class, 'update']);
```

**ContactController**

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{

    $contact = new Contact([
        'name' => $request->name,
        'address' => $request->address,
        'nic' => $request->nic          
    ]);
    $contact->update();
    return response()->json('Contact Updateddd!');
}
```

**Model**

```
class Contact extends Model{

        protected $table = "contact";
        protected $primaryKey = "id";
        protected $fillable = ["name", "address", "nic"];

}
```

**Front End Vue JS**

Save records and Updating records i adding the same form with validation. save is working but update dosen't working.

```
<form @submit.prevent="save">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Employee Name</label>
          <input v-model="task.name"  type="text" class="form-control">
         
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Employee Address</label>
          <input  v-model="task.address" type="text" class="form-control" >
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Nic</label>
          <input  v-model="task.nic" type="text"  class="form-control">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
      </form>
```

table records view from the database successfullly i attached code below. each rows i put the edit button for edit. when i click the edit button editable row records are passing to the form successfully. after that make the changes and click edit records not i updated what is the error i **got i attached above.
table code**

```
            <td>{{ task.id }}</td>
            <td>{{ task.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ task.address }}</td>
            <td>{{ task.nic }}</td>
            <td>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @click="edit(task)">Edit</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" @click="remove(task)">Delete</button>
            </td>
```

Save and update code . save is working update only not working please check the update code
i attached the full code for easy to find out the error.

```
 import Vue from 'vue';
 import axios from 'axios';

 Vue.use(axios)
  
  export default {
    name: 'Crud',
    data () {
      return {
         result: {},
          task:{
            id: '',
            name: '',
            address: '',
            nic: ''
          }

         
      }
      
    },
    created() {
        console.log("created() called.....");
        this.loadTaks();
    },

    mounted() {
          console.log("mounted() called.......");
         
      },
    methods: {
           loadTaks()
           {
                Vue.use(axios);
                 console.log("LoadTasks() calling....");
                // var page = "http://localhost:8088/api/v1/employee/get-all-employees";
                 var page = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/contact";
                 axios.get(page)
                  .then(
                      ({data})=>{
                        console.log(data);
                        this.result = data;
                      }
                  );
           },
           save()
           {
              if(this.task.id == '')
              {
                this.saveData();
              }
              else
              {
                this.updateData();
              }       
           },
           saveData()
           {
             axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/save', this.task)
             .then(
                  ({data})=>{
                    this.loadTaks();
                    this.task.name = '';
                    this.address = '',
                    this.nic = '',
           
                    alert("saved!!!");
                  }
             )
           },
           updateData()
           {
              var url = '127.0.0.1:8000/api/update/'+this.task.id;
              axios.put(url, this.task)
              .then(
                ({data})=>{
                  this.task.name = '';
                  this.address = '',
                  this.nic = ''
                  this.id = ''
                  alert("Updated!!!");
                  this.loadTaks();
                }
              );

           },
           edit(task){
                this.task = task;
              
           },
           remove(task){
              var url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/contact/delete/'+this.task.id;
              axios.delete();
           }

      }

  }
  </script>
```

Have a problem on the controller update funtion what was the error here

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{

    $contact = new Contact([
        'name' => $request->name,
        'address' => $request->address,
        'nic' => $request->nic          
    ]);
    $contact->update();
    return response()->json('Contact Updateddd!');
}
```

Comment: I don't see anywhere in your js code that you are calling the `/update/'+this.task.id;` route.

Comment: i am calling Route::put('/update/{id}',[App\Http\Controllers\ContactController::class, 'update']);      like that is the wrong

Comment: i chenged like but not working this 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/update/'+this.task.id;

Comment: Is there any error message you can show us?

Comment: ya error on the controller update part

Comment: Your update function seem to be creating a new record instead of updating an existing one. You should find the record to update first, and latter update it properties.